# Drupal allow multiple users to add and modify content

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I want that multiple users can add things to a **list**.
For example user 1 creates sth. like "What is needed for the best pizza in the world?" than other users should add sth. like 500 grams of whatever, 300 grams of sth.else ...
If it's plain text i know how it's done, but i want sth like "click button for new ingredience".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a content type e.g. "Recipes".

On that content type you'll have a field (Text) e.g. "Ingredients".

In the settings for this field you'll have 'Number of values' set to Unlimited.

Then when adding/editing a Recipe you'll see "Add another item" under the Ingredients list.

If you wanted to alter the button text from "Add new item" to "Click button for new ingredience" (or something else) you'd need a hook_form_alter() function in a custom module.

Comment: Thanx a lot. Do you have any idea how i can get the added item to be a custom content type on itself? Cause i need more than one field added at a time. For example ingredient, price, weight etc.

Comment: Yes you will use a "Reference" field instead and for settings the reference field will be to a content type that has all of those fields. I assume you are using Drupal 8 or 9 which has this in core, else if 7 it will require the contrib module entityreference.

Comment: Works ;-) is it possible to have the reference expanded? Now i've sth like a list, and after save i've to open the item to edit the fields.

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot do that out of the box and not sure of any contributed modules that enable that; but interested if you found anything.